# Bounce into the air

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, angle, rigid-bodies

I'm working on a 2D game, and I need a projectile prefab bounce/flap/jump in the middle of the air after the player press the mouse.
In this case, while it moves along the X-axis, it is necessary to apply a force inversely proportional to the projectile's angular direction on the Y-axis in relation to its own x-axis line (only when it has a negative angle in relation to the horizontal line). The new velocity should be minimally lower than the previous one, divided by the percentage of "SlowDownFactor."
Something like that:
[angle bounce description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PabMC.png)

I'm new to Unity, so I don't know exactly which commands to use to apply this inverse force, I've already taken a good look at the documentation, but I haven't been very successful.
The code I have so far:

```
{
    [Range( 0, 1 )]
    public float SlowDownFactor = 1;
    private Rigidbody2D red_rigidbody;


    public void ExecuteAirSpecial()
    {
        red_rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Vector3 redAng;
        red_rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.Angle(redAng.y, -redAng.y) * SlowDownFactor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to underestand what you want to achieve. If your proyectile's path does not follow a normal parabolic trayectory rpovided by the rigidbody physiscs when the force is applied, you would need to explain the exact trayectory and angular behaviour of the entity to see if someone is able to help you. The best approach would be to do it first with an [animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html). If you are not happy witht the result or you want to still achive with physics, maybe the animation approach helps you explain the proyectiles behaviour with a small clip.

Another approach would be to code the trayectory and angular position of the proyectile with calculations in the code, but not physics applied to the entity. A more ambitious approach than the animation one.

Anyhow, I would suggest that you first try to launch your proyectile adding a force, and checking the behaviour or a normal rigid body, and then you will be able to move on towards the more sophisticated behaviour that you want.

Comment: So, the movement is, in fact, a parabola. It's like a cannonball, you know?
But when the player uses one of his skills, the ball must make a "bounce" in the air, like jumping. And the idea is that it is proportionally inverse to the angle and acceleration of the trajectory that the ball would be travelling on the Y-axis (when it is falling). I don't need to change anything on the X-axis.
If I can get the ball acceleration over the Y-axis and apply it inversely to rigidbody2d, it should work.
But since I'm new to Unity, I have no idea which command to use, and how, I can get this data.

Answer (score 0):

So, I took another look at the Unity documentation (after finally getting to sleep and rest), and the solution was straightforward. It was just a matter of using the correct nomenclature.
Here is the code working:

```
{
    [Range( 0, 1 )]
    public float SlowDownFactor = 1;
    private Rigidbody2D red_rigidbody;


    public void ExecuteAirSpecial()
    {
        red_rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Vector2 red_velocity = red_rigidbody.velocity;
        if (red_velocity.y < 0)
        {
            red_rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, -red_velocity.y) / (SlowDownFactor / 100));
        }
    }
}
```